# Macro stops after Workbook.Open

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy open a workbook, copy a range and paste it into another workbook. After the workbook is opened and the range selected the macro stops.

If I use Workbook.close later in the code, the macro stops at the same point but the the workbook is not even opened.

I saw in other threads the "shift key" problem when using Workbook.Open and this is not the case.

```
Sub importSpecialist()


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("myworksheet")

Dim lws As Integer
lws = ws.Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row

Dim savePath As String
Dim saveName As String
Dim saveMonth As String
Dim fileExtension As String
Dim fullPath As String
Dim version As Integer

Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

savePath = "C:\mypath\"
saveName = "myname_"
saveMonth = Format(Date, "mm")
fileExtension = ".xlsx"
fullPath = savePath & saveName & saveMonth & fileExtension

Debug.Print fullPath

If FSO.fileexists(fullPath) Then
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(fullPath)
    wb1.Sheets(1).Range("C4:C18").Copy
        For i = 1 To lws
            On Error Resume Next
            If ws.Range("B" & (i + 2)) = Format(Date, "mm/yyyy") Then
                ws.Cells(Range("N" & (i + 2))).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it like this :

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    xl.Workbooks.Open (Worksheets("MAIN").Range("B7").Value)//your path
    xl.Visible = False //or true
   //your code here
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
```

''and if you what to select a range from it use xl.Worksheets().Range().Select